# Change quantum value in cloudsim stimulator

Tags: cloud, round-robin, cloudsim

It is possible to change the quantum value when I use the  CloudleschedulerTimeShared  in order to apply Round robin algorithm for scheduling the tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Such a feature is not implemented in CloudSim. If you try [CloudSim Plus](http://cloudsimplus.org), it has an implementation of the Linux Scheduler that defines the quantum based on the priority you give to Cloudlets. Check the [CloudletSchedulerCompletelyFair class](https://github.com/manoelcampos/cloudsim-plus/blob/master/cloudsim-plus/src/main/java/org/cloudbus/cloudsim/schedulers/cloudlet/CloudletSchedulerCompletelyFair.java).

You just need to create VMs, set this scheduler and define priorities for your Cloudlets. In this case, the priorities must lay between [-20 and 19]. Below is an example snippet:

```
vm.setCloudletScheduler(new CloudletSchedulerCompletelyFair());
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){
    Cloudlet c = new CloudletSimple(CLOUDLET_LEN, CLOUDLET_PES);
    c.setPriority(i);  //you must define the priority in your own way
    cloudletList.add(c);
}
```

Check a complete example [here](https://github.com/manoelcampos/cloudsim-plus/blob/master/cloudsim-plus-examples/src/main/java/org/cloudsimplus/examples/schedulers/LinuxCompletelyFairSchedulerExample.java).

Comment: HI, thank you for your answer, is there a way to implement the linux scheduler or any other scheduler using quantum in CloudSim. Because i'm currently using iFogSim and could not use CloudSImPlus ?